# How to expect some (but not all) arguments with RSpec should_receive?

Tags: ruby, rspec, expectations

```
class Foo
  def bar(a, b)
  ...

Foo.should_receive( :bar )
```

expects bar to be called with any arguments.

```
Foo.should_receive( :bar ).with( :baz, :qux )
```

expects :baz and :qux to be passed in as the params.

How to expect the first param to equal :baz, and not care about the other params?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use the `anything` matcher:

```
Foo.should_receive(:bar).with(:baz, anything)
```

Comment: This works. The caveat is you need one `anything` for each param.

Comment: I am not sure whether it was added afterwards, but RSpec has any_args so that for `bar(a, b, c)` you can do `Foo.should_receive(:bar).with(:baz, any_args)`

Comment: Thanks @rubyprince very much, great tip!

Comment: I have found anything does not work unless it is the last argument, which is frustrating. Eg. this does not work: `.with(:baz, anything, :foo)`

Comment: I'm going to drop this here to show how you can do this with an object param: 
`expect(MyObjectRepository).to receive(:create).with({ filename: anything, something_else: some_variable_declared_above })`

Comment: A complement: It's possible to match the type of parameter, like this: `expect(RegsiterWorker).to have_received(:perform_async).with(instance_of(Integer), "onboarding")` - In my context, the first parameter is a number which I can't handle on my spec. It enough knows it's a number`

Answer (score 33):

For **Rspec 1.3** `anything` doesn't work when your method is receiving a **hash** as an argument, so please try with `hash_including(:key => val)`:

```
Connectors::Scim::Preprocessors::Builder.
    should_receive(:build).
    with(
      hash_including(:connector => connector)
      ).
    and_return(preprocessor)
}
```

Answer (score 25):

There's another way to do this, which is the block form of `receive`: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#use-a-block-to-verify-arguments

```
expect(Foo).to receive(:bar) do |args|
  expect(args[0]).to eq(:baz)
end
```